# In Blazor WebAssembly, how to include hash in static file link/script reference in index.html for cache-busting?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

In server-side ASP.NET, we can do `asp-append-version=true` on static assets in a .cshtml file in order to automatically append a hash of the file to the filename.  But, in Blazor WebAssembly, this doesn't work, which makes sense because I have a simple index.html file that bootstraps Blazor and references static files, not a server-modified file.

**So is there a good way in Blazor WebAssembly's index.html file to append a hash to the URL of a static file**, similar in outcome to the old `asp-append-version=true`?  For example, to make `<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />` become `<link href="css/site.css?v=1234abc..." rel="stylesheet" />`, and thus changes to site.css on deployment will result in all clients GETting the newly changed static file, rather than relying on cache?

Comment: Did you consider replacing the index.html by a .cshtml page on your server ?

Comment: I thought there might be a client-only way of doing it, but I suppose I can do that if necessary.

Comment: I don't know other way with ASP.Net Core. This cannot be done in client side.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Where you able to try the .cshtml approach? Did it work?

Comment: It seems that later versions of Blazor retrieve the .css file from WebAssembly runtime, so cache-busting is not required.  Not exactly sure if I fully understand this, though.

Comment: This issue mentions there is a way to do it, but I haven't figured it out yet: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17036

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-boot-resource-loading

As well as the section to change the filename extension of dll files.  It's silly that this functionality is not available out-of-the box because it's a best practice in web programming.

Comment: the .cshtml approach breaks the client routing mechanism. it seems the index.html must be static.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a workaround for this. I have created a controller that will handle the request, read the index.html, search and replace a "{version}" placeholder and then return the content.

First step is to modify the Startup.cs:

```
            //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");
```

Then create a controller like this one:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static string _processedIndexFile;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = CacheProfileNames.NoCache)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return ProcessAndReturnIndexFile();
    }

    private IActionResult ProcessAndReturnIndexFile()
    {
        if (_processedIndexFile == null)
        {
            IFileInfo file = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("index.html");
            _processedIndexFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.PhysicalPath);
            _processedIndexFile = _processedIndexFile.Replace("{version}", AppInfo.CompiledOn.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'-'HH'-'mm'-'ss"));
        }
        return Content(_processedIndexFile, "text/html");
    }
}
```

And finally inside the index.html file, use urls like:

```
<link href="css/app.min.css?v={version}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This also allows you to do some other things before returning the file inside the Index method, like checking if falling back to index.html is correct for the current request:

```
        // Check for incorrect fallback routes
        if (Request.Path.Value?.Contains("api/") == true)
            return NotFound();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a quite easy solution to this if you are using ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WASM:

Create a new empty Razor Page in your **Server** project for Blazor WASM. Call it `BlazorIndex` or something else you like.

It will look something like this:

```
@page
@model BlazorAppIndividualAccounts.Server.Pages.BlazorIndexModel
@{
}
```

Now add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Like this:

```
@page
@model BlazorAppIndividualAccounts.Server.Pages.BlazorIndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
}
```

Then edit `Program.cs` and replace `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");` with `app.MapFallbackToPage("/BlazorIndex");`

Now copy your values from Client wwwroot `index.html` to `BlazorIndex.cshtml`. Then remove `index.html` from Client wwwroot.

Complete example with `asp-append-version="true"` for `css/app.css` and `AuthenticationService.js`:

```
@page
@model BlazorAppIndividualAccounts.Server.Pages.BlazorIndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorAppIndividualAccounts</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link href="BlazorAppIndividualAccounts.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you will append a hash to the URL of static files and you can also use any other feature from Razor Pages that you like.

[image]